# How do I create a Gmail client for Windows 8/ 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, gmail, windows-8.1, gmail-api

Just upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 7 and found that there is no official GMail metro app. MetroMail isn't official, is it?

Anyway, so I was wondering what is required to create a GMail metro app. Does one need to have some kind of a contract with Google for the api?

I am a web developer and a GMail client seems to be a good way to start developing metro apps as well.

Comment: Sure the WIndows 8 version doesn't work for 8.1? http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/metromail/e5dda0fa-ffa9-45e8-9334-0ee9b4341811

Comment: Sure it does; but like I said, MetroMail isn't made by Google, is it? There is no official app.

Comment: In order to use the Gmail API you just have to follow the [ToS](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/terms) and Google's branding guidelines.